# problema com nav no css

Tags: html, css

Bom eu criei um nav com a class = topbar e tentei chamar no css porém não está indo:

```
<nav class="topBar">
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Inicio</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
<img src="images/logosecure.png">
</header>
```

css

```
    @charset "utf-8";
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
}
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topBar nav{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #000;
}
.topBar nav ul li{
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
.topBar nav ul li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

foto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

`.topBar nav` irá procurar um elemento `<nav>` dentro de outro elemento qualquer que tenha a classe `topBar`.

O que você quer é `nav.topBar`, um elemento `<nav>` que possua a classe `topBar`

Comment: nav.topbar{
 width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
 background: #000;
}
 nav.topbar ul li{
 background: #000;
 color:#fff;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
 nav.topbar ul li:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
 eu fiz isso e continuou do mesmo jeito man.

Comment: Verifique se não tem outro CSS que está alterando os mesmos elementos

Comment: não tem man o css ta só com aquele codigo.

Comment: Você mudou o nome da classe no CSS de `.topBar` para `.topbar`, no HTML também?

Comment: Opa man eu consegui arrumar criando uma div contendo o nav, vlw man ( criei a div com o nome topbar) e no css botei .topbar nav.